# Change grouping color with highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have a barplot with different categories, I customized the bar color for each category but I dont know how to change the under graph point color

My data :

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

x = structure(list(stat = c("abandonne_pro", "admissible", "admissible", 
                            "admissible", "non_recu", "refuse", "refuse", "en_cours", 
                            "non_recu"), 
                   annee_recep = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17897, 18262, 17897, 17532, 17897, 17897, 17532), class = "Date"), 
                   nb_stat = c(4L, 57L, 112L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L)), 
              row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
              class = "data.frame",
              .Names = c("stat", "annee_recep", "nb_stat"))
```

Add the color variable :

```
x = x %>%
  mutate(
    color = case_when(
      stat == 'abandonne_pro' ~ '#87CEEB',
      stat == 'admissible' ~ '#7CFC00',
      stat == 'non_recu' ~ '#FF7F50',
      stat == 'refuse' ~ '#FF0000',
      stat == 'en_cours' ~ '#FFFF00',
      TRUE ~ '#C0C0C0'
    ),
    date = format(annee_recep, format="%Y")
  )
```

The Graphic :

```
hchart(
  x,
  "column", 
  hcaes(x = annee_recep, y = nb_stat, group = stat, color = color)
) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"), type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(
    title = list(text = 'Date'),
    type = 'datetime'
  ) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = "Nombre de chantier")
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_gridlight())
```

The output :

[image]

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to set the colors manually using `hc_colors()` instead of mapping on the color aesthetic. Try this:

```r
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

x <- structure(list(
  stat = c(
    "abandonne_pro", "admissible", "admissible",
    "admissible", "non_recu", "refuse", "refuse", "en_cours",
    "non_recu"
  ),
  annee_recep = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17897, 18262, 17897, 17532, 17897, 17897, 17532), class = "Date"),
  nb_stat = c(4L, 57L, 112L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L)
),
row.names = c(NA, -9L),
class = "data.frame",
.Names = c("stat", "annee_recep", "nb_stat")
)

x <- x %>%
  mutate(
    color = case_when(
      stat == 'abandonne_pro' ~ '#87CEEB',
      stat == 'admissible' ~ '#7CFC00',
      stat == 'non_recu' ~ '#FF7F50',
      stat == 'refuse' ~ '#FF0000',
      stat == 'en_cours' ~ '#FFFF00',
      TRUE ~ '#C0C0C0'
    ),
    date = format(annee_recep, format="%Y")
  )

# Filter dataset
x <- filter(x, stat != 'en_cours')
# Named color vector
color_vec <- count(x, stat, color) %>% 
  select(stat, color) %>% 
  deframe() %>% 
  unname()

hchart(
  x,
  "column", 
  hcaes(x = annee_recep, y = nb_stat, group = stat)
) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"), type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(
    title = list(text = 'Date'),
    type = 'datetime'
  ) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = "Nombre de chantier")
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_gridlight()) %>% 
  hc_colors(colors = color_vec)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, I want to have one color for one specific 'stat', with your solution, if I filter on `filter(x, stat != 'en_cours')` colors will swap each other ...

Comment: Hi Mostafa. I was aware of this problem. Hardcoding is never a good choice. I just edited my code. Still not the perfect solution compared to ggplot2 scale_color_identiy ... But have a look. To allow for filtering I introduced a color vector which contains only the colors for the stats present in your df. As an example I worked with `filter(x, stat != 'en_cours')`

Comment: Thanks stefan it's doing the job very smart trick ;) I was thinking about adding all `stat` and give them 0 in the `nb_stat` column by a basic `rbind` to keep the color order ... but your way of doing is definetly better !